# Unable to make amount with 2 decimal places with php code

Tags: php

Do I need to define my variable `$amount` in a different way.  I am having difficulty trying to get it that way its displaying as [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7Hu3.jpg)

Its adding 2 more zeros to everything. What am I missing.

I was wanting to see if I could get the dollar sign included in this image as well. Not sure if that is extra code or if that is a function that needs to be added in.

```
<?php  
$amount = '';
    echo number_format(floor($amount*100)/100,2, '.', ''); 
 ?>
 <html>
 <head>
    <title>Display Transaction Table</title>

<script>

</script>
</head>

 <body>
 <h1>Transactions</h1>
 <div id="myTable">
 <input class="search" placeholder="Search" /><!--Not Required, but useful-->

<table class="data-table" action="transactions.php" id ="myTable">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="sort" data-sort="id">ID</th>
            <th class="sort" data-sort="fund">Fund</th>
            <th class="sort" data-sort="department">Department</th>
            <th class="sort" data-sort="code">Code</th>
            <th class="sort" data-sort="year">Year</th>
            <th class="sort" data-sort="date">Date</th>
            <th class="sort" data-sort="project">Project</th>
            <th class="sort" data-sort="description">Description</th>
            <th class="sort" data-sort="amount">Amount</th>
            <th class="sort" data-sort="detail">Detail</th>
            <th class="sort" data-sort="po">PO</th>
            <th class="sort" data-sort="type">Type</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="list">
    <?php
    $transaction_id = 1;


    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query))
     {
    $amount  = $row['amount'] == 0 ? '' : number_format($row['amount']);

        echo '<tr>
                <td class="id">'.$transaction_id.'</td>
                <td class="fund">'.$row['fund'].'</td>
                <td class="department">'.$row['department'].'</td>
                <td class="code">'.$row['code_name'].'</td>
                <td class="year">'.$row['budget_year'].'</td>
                <td class="date">'.$row['entry_date'].'</td>
                <td class="project">'.$row['project_name'].'</td>
                <td class="description">'.$row['item_desc'].'</td>
                <td class="amount">'.$row['amount'].'</td>
                <td class="detail">'.$row['detail'].'</td>
                <td class="po">'.$row['PO'].'</td>
                <td class="type">'.$row['type'].'</td>
                <td><a href="edittest.php?edit='.$row["transaction_id"].'">Edit</a></td>  
            </tr>';


        $transaction_id++;
    }?>


    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are not using `$amount` in your table. You are using `$row['amount']`.

```
// change this
<td class="amount">'.$row['amount'].'</td>

// to this
<td class="amount">'.$amount.'</td>
```

Comment: I tried that but still giving me error of A non-numeric value encountered when I change it .

Comment: Sure thing 
PHP Warning:  A non-numeric value encountered in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\transactions.php on line 145

This is how I have it written
$amount = '';
   echo number_format(floor($amount*100)/100,2, '.', '');

Comment: When `$amount = ''` is is not a number. Why are you setting `$amount` to `''`?

Comment: echo number_format(floor($amount*100)/100,2, '.', '');

Comment: That line does not appear to be doing anything for you. Can you remove it?

Comment: Removing it it makes the amounts at 40 and 50 and rounds up one that I have as 4.99 to 5  so it is rounding

Comment: What is "40 and 50"? Line numbers? BTW, your `number_format($row['amount'])` is not allowing for 2 decimal places. That should be `number_format($row['amount'],2)`.

Comment: No there are amounts within my table that should be $40.00  and $50.00 and its displaying as
40
50
and the one that is 4.99 is displaying as 5

Comment: the comment:

What is "40 and 50"? Line numbers? BTW, your 

       number_format($row['amount'])  
is not allowing for 2 decimal places. That should be 

    number_format($row['amount'],2) THIS WORKS!!

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the $amount calculation like below:

```
$amount = (!empty($row['amount'])) ? number_format($row['amount'], 2) : 0;
```

and change the amount line :

```
'<td class="amount">'.$row['amount'].'</td>'
```

To

```
'<td class="amount">'. $amount .'</td>'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wouldn't using `intval()` remove the decimal places that Heidi wants two of?

Comment: Yes thats why I have used it only in the !empty condition to check whether its a valid number. Because if its not a valid number then intval would give us zero which will lead to the false condition.

Comment: If the number retrieved from the database is `0.1234` your code will result in `$amount` being `0` rather than `0.12`.

Comment: That is a pretty valid point. I hadn't thought of that. Thanks for pointing it out. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Changing code from

```
 $amount  = $row['amount'] == 0 ? '' : number_format($row['amount']);
```

to

```
$amount  = $row['amount'] == 0 ? '' : number_format($row['amount'],2);
```

This has updated my table !!
Thanks everyone